# url authentication with pinax

Tags: django, pinax

In the pinax-project-account when a page is rendered we can, with the tag `{% if not user.is_authenticated %}`, control the context rendered.

My question is, how is it possible for someone to control which page appears? Say a user tries to hard code a url 
on the address bar and the user is not supposed to see that url.
Any hint on where to start?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `django.contrib.auth`, and specially the  [`login_required`, `permission_required` and `user_passes_test`  decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users).

Comment: Thank you very much bruno ! I will immediately start following your advise. As soon as I finish I will accept you. Thanks again !